# How to work with kafka In .NET Application

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka

i am trying to read message from Producer through Kafka and producer server has ip 10.11.129.12 and port 9092 and i have verified telnet that port is opened. Now i downloaded kafka dll's and i am using below code snippet to read message ,
i have few questions like ,do i need to install kafka client on my server receiving side or Nugget donwload DLL's `KafkaNet,KafkaNet.Model,KafkaNet.Protocol`  is sufficient ??
below is source code used in .net 4.6 which i sufficient?They have given the userid and password of kafka server,where do i put those in below code

```
using KafkaNet;
using KafkaNet.Model;
using KafkaNet.Protocol;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Kafka_Net
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.183.126.122:9092");
  

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnReceive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string topicName = "test";
            var options = new KafkaOptions(uri);
            var brokerRouter = new BrokerRouter(options);
            var consumer = new Consumer(new ConsumerOptions(topicName, brokerRouter));
            foreach (var msg in consumer.Consume())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.Value));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            if(txtMessage.Text ==string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Message","Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }
            
            this.Clear();
        }
        void Clear()
        {
            this.txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
            this.txtMessage.Focus();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Clear();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i corrected it,But above code is sufficient ? i am running but it is taking lot of time to read and i am waiting the out put.Do i need to install kafka client?

Comment: I thought `Confluent.Kafka` was the de facto client.  Are you not able to use that?

Comment: @mtmkThey have given the userid and password of kafka server,where do i put those in below code

Comment: The address in your code isn't the same as the question...? KafkaNet hasn't been updated in 8+ years. I don't think you should be using that. Username and password are usually SASL options in your client configuration.. Also kafka isn't an HTTP protocol, so remove http:// from the address

Comment: @mtmk Confluent.Kafka can be used with console application??

Comment: Your code shown here is using a GUI framework, but yes, it can

Comment: Is there any sample code i can download for Confluent.Kafka